# insert into a table with select

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I have two tables with these schema:

```
student(id,name,dept_name, tot_cred)
instructor(id,name,dept_name,salary)
```

and the question is:

> Insert every student whose tot_cred attribute is greater than 100 as
> an instructor in the same department, with a salary of $10,000.

I try this query but I dont know how set salary for student $10,000:

```
insert into instructor (id,name,dept_name,salary) 
  select id,name,dept_name 
    from student 
   where tot_cred > 100
```

Comment: I assume this is a homework question.  We're happy to help students but we're not in the habit of doing your homework for you.  Show us what you've tried.  Tell us what you're seeing (An error?  If so, what error?  Incorrect results?  If so, what are the expected results and what are the actual results).  Tell us where specifically you're unsure.  You've also tagged this question for 4 different databases-- MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, and PostgreSQL.  Each uses a different dialect of SQL so you might need different syntax on each.  Which one are you actually using?

Comment: I try this query but I dont know how set salary for student $10,000:                        insert into instructor (id,name,dept_name,salary) select id,name,dept_name from student where tot_cred > 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the constant value.  Personally, I'd add an alias in the `select` to document that the constant is intended to be the `salary` although it's not necessary.  Different databases may have different rules for how to create that alias and you haven't told us what database you're using so I'm guessing on the syntax.

```
insert into instructor (id,name,dept_name,salary) 
  select id,name,dept_name,10000 as salary
    from student 
   where tot_cred > 100
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO instructor
(id,
NAME,
dept_name,
salary)
SELECT id,
NAME,
dept_name,
10000 AS salary
FROM   student
WHERE  tot_cred >= 100;